# Android SDK 3.0: openForRead returns AccessToken although permission for app was revoked by user

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

My FB integration is quite simple. For registering and login of the user I only need to get the FB token via the SDK and then I hand it over to my server. There are no further graph calls etc. from my app. Everything is done from the server.
I use the following static class to get it, which works fine. Except for the case where the user revokes access for the app on the FB homepage, there I still get the old access token, that my server obviously cannot use anymore.

Any way I can force the SDK to get me a valid token and if necessary ask the user for the permissions once again?

```
public static void getAccessToken(Fragment fragment, final FacebookTokenListener listener) {
        Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            Session session = new Session.Builder(fragment.getActivity()).setApplicationId(
                    fragment.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id)).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            currentSession = session;
        }
        if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
            openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(fragment);

            if (openRequest != null) {
                openRequest.setPermissions(Configuration.FB_PERMISSIONS);
                openRequest.setCallback(new StatusCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "call " + session.getAccessToken() + " , state: " + state.name() + " ,exception: "
                                + (exception == null ? "null" : exception.getMessage()));
                        if (session.isOpened()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "fb token: " + session.getAccessToken());
                            listener.onAccessTokenReceived(session.getAccessToken());
                        }
                    }
                });
                currentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "fb token: " + currentSession.getAccessToken());
            listener.onAccessTokenReceived(currentSession.getAccessToken());
        }
    }
```